# Mocking C# Static Functions that require data access

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write some unit tests for an existing project (I know maybe too late), but I have a static object:

```
public class UserLevel : ClassBase
    {
    
    public static DataSet ListDataset()
        {
            var query = new Query(ConfigLogin.LoginConnection, "exec usp_UserLevels_List;");

            if (query.ReadQuery())
            {
                return query.DataSet;
            }
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

As you can see this calls

```
/// <summary>
    /// The Query class is the main class used for SQL database reading. There are a number of methods in this class what will help you retrieve data out of the database.
    /// </summary>
    public class Query
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// SqlCommand is the command that the query is to run. Usually set by the constructor of the Query class.
        /// </summary>
        public SqlCommand SqlCommand { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// CurrentConnection is where the query will attempt to connect to.
        /// </summary>
        public Connection CurrentConnection { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// DataSet is populated after a query has been run, it is the raw data recieved from the database.
        /// </summary>
        public DataSet DataSet { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This varible is set when a query has been run, true if successful, false if not.
        /// </summary>
        private bool _readQuery = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// The status of the query after execution. The details are as follows:
        /// - SaveOk
        /// - SaveError
        /// - UpdateError
        /// - UniqueDuplication
        /// - NoSave
        /// - TransactionError
        /// </summary>
        public ClassBase.SaveDetails SaveDetails { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of results returned from a query.
        /// </summary>
        public int NumberofResults
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Blank Query for pagination
        /// </summary>
        public Query()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Query with a query instruction while setting a custom connection. This could be a stored procedure execution, or a select statement etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connection">The connection object for which the query will be run against.</param>
        /// <param name="query">The query string that will be run on the server.</param>
        /// <param name="cloneConnection">Boolean to skip the connection cloning. Defaults to false so by default it will clone the connection. Typically leave this unless you are using transactions from the code.</param>
        public Query(Connection connection, string query, bool cloneConnection = true)
        {
            CurrentConnection = cloneConnection ? connection.CloneConnection() : connection;
            SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, CurrentConnection.Conn);

            RunQuery();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Query with a query instruction while using the global connection. This could be a stored procedure execution, or a select statement etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">The query string that will be run on the server.</param>
        public Query(string query)
        {
            CurrentConnection = ClassAppConfig.GlobalConnection.CloneConnection();
            SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, CurrentConnection.Conn);

            RunQuery();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Query with a query instruction and parameters while setting a custom connection. This could be a stored procedure execution, or a select statement etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connection">The connection object for which the query will be run against.</param>
        /// <param name="query">The query string that will be run on the server.</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">A list of SqlParameter that is passed with the query to the database. This is neccessary over including the parameters in the query to prevent from SQL injection attacks.</param>
        /// <param name="cloneConnection">Boolean to skip the connection cloning. Defaults to false so by default it will clone the connection. Typically leave this unless you are using transactions from the code.</param>
        public Query(Connection connection, string query, List<SqlParameter> parameters, bool cloneConnection = true)
        {
            CurrentConnection = cloneConnection ? connection.CloneConnection() : connection;
            SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, CurrentConnection.Conn);

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
            }

            RunQuery();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Query with a query instruction and parameters. This could be a stored procedure execution, or a select statement etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">The query string that will be run on the server.</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">A list of SqlParameter that is passed with the query to the database. This is neccessary over including the parameters in the query to prevent from SQL injection attacks.</param>
        public Query(string query, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            CurrentConnection = ClassAppConfig.GlobalConnection.CloneConnection();
            SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, CurrentConnection.Conn);

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            RunQuery();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Once a Query object has been set up with a query string and neccessary parameters, ReadQuery will execute the query and return a dataset to the DataSet attribute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Boolean: True if the query ran without error, false if there was an error during execution of the query.</returns>
        public bool ReadQuery()
        { return _readQuery; }

        protected void RunQuery()
        {
            bool returnValue = false;
            try
            {
                if (CurrentConnection.Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    CurrentConnection.Conn.Open();

                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand);

                ClassDebug.AddDebug(SqlCommand);

                DataSet = new DataSet();

                da.Fill(DataSet);

                returnValue = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                returnValue = false;
            }

            if (CurrentConnection.CurrentTransaction == null)
                SqlCommand.Connection.Close();

            _readQuery = returnValue;
        }
```

It would therefore be nice to be able to Mock the Dataset that is returned from this class, rather than calling RunQuery (which calls the DB).

I have tried following a few tutorials but they seem to start from a much simpler point. Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: You can't mock a static method. Refactor the code. This code probably predates (or ignores) a lot of best practices and conventions, like dependency injection and not prefixing your stored procedure names.

Comment: Well, to be fair, you can't use test doubles with *this* method because it is welded to the database, not because it is `static`.  But yes, it would have to be refactored, and if you're going to do that, you might as well use a more "conventional" approach.

Comment: I see a frightening lack of `using` to dispose classes that need disposing, and things like `CloneConnection` that make me think connections are going to be reused in manner that they shouldn't be reused. Rather than writing tests for this, consider writing tests for code using it, and use those tests to migrate away from this to something more modern like Dapper (assuming your code does attempt to build objects at some point, and is not also married to `DataSet`). When wrapped using interfaces, such code is also mockable. This is not, and I wouldn't sink effort into making it.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice.